# What is 301 xml parser error and please explain with examples?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

I am writing unit test cases for XML Parser error codes for 300,301,302 etc but I am unable to find in google search good examples, with real world examples. Please any one explain exact real world examples to use for testdata purpose.

Simple example of XML as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Summary>
<State>
<Code>0</Code>
<Desc>success</Desc>
<msg>Processed Successfully</msg>
</State>
</Summary>
```

Comment: There are many XML parsers out there, we have no idea which one you are using. The error code appears to be in an XML document anyway, so it sounds like your problem is with the XML output of some unspecified piece of software and not with an error message emitted by your unspecified XML parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**301 is not a standard XML parser error.**  However, it is used in IBM's RNX0351 messages, so you may find their [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_61/rzasc/sc092507227.htm), excerpted below, to be useful:

```
300 The parser reached the end of the document before the document was complete.
301 The %HANDLER procedure for XML-INTO or XML-SAX returned a non-zero value, causing the XML parsing to end.
302 The parser does not support the requested CCSID value or the first character of the XML document was not '<'.
303 The document was too large for the parser to handle. The parser attempted to parse the incomplete document, but the data at the end of the document was necessary for the parsing to complete.
```

Based on this, you cannot create an XML document that'll elicit a 301 as it is due to the parsing code, not the data.